# ctrl + v do not work on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, copy-paste

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does not work on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> works.

Right clicking on the text and choosing "Cut" works. Right clicking and choosing "paste" right after does not work.

This happens in every application on my system. Notepad, word etc.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem happens when I have Open Office open. Doing some copying/pasting in that program and then trying in other programs is when the error will occur. If I close Open Office everything returns to normal.

My Open Office does not have any keyboard shortcuts set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Close all applications, programs running in the systray, application launchers, etc. Does the problem persist?

Answer (score 2):

A possible explanation is that some process has placed a global system hook on the keyboard and is intercepting the ctrl-v.

This can be verified by booting into Safe mode (F8 when booting Windows), in which only Windows is started without any third-party product. If this doesn't happen in this mode, then some installed product is surely causing the problem.

The product [RootKit Unhooker](http://www.antirootkit.com/software/RootKit-Unhooker.htm) detects "SSDT Hooks Detection and Restoring". SSDT here means the [System Service Dispatch Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Service_Dispatch_Table) used for placing system hooks. It might detect which product is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an application is overriding the keykombination? Is it working in other programs? Notepad? Word? or only in Windows Explorer?

Comment: This happens in every application on my system. Notepad, word etc.